# i am getting the output as terminates , what i want is to skip 5 alone, please debug

Tags: python

I tried to skip just 5 and print everything else from the `range` but it just prints `terminates`. Can anyone please check?

```
for i in range(1,10):
    if(i==5):
        continue
        print(i)
print("terminates")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix the indentation of the first print statement.
Try this:

```py
for i in range(1,10):
    if(i==5):
        continue
    print(i)
print("terminates")
```